# Backbone.js model and view binding on re-rendering

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

So I have a model with default attributes set and a login page where I am storing the values of the username and password in to a collection.

```
//collection
var userProfileCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: UserProfileModel
});

//Model
var UserProfileModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        userName: "",
        password: ""
    }
});

//View

var LoginRegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                this.render();  
            },
            render: function() {

            //loads the template containing the form
            $("#loginPage").html(loginregisteruser_Template);

            click event(){
           var username = $("#username").val();
           var password = $("#password").val();

           //userProfileModel is set as a global since another view accesses the model's attributes and their values
                var userProfileColl = new userProfileCollection();
                userProfileModel.set("userName", username);
                userProfileModel.set("password", password);
                userProfileColl.add(userProfileModel);

                window.location = "#" //home
}
}
});

//router
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes:{
        'login': "login"
},
login: function() {

                this.view = new LoginRegisterView({
                    model: userProfileModel,
                    el: $('#loginPage')
                });

    });
```

So my question is whenever I refresh the login page, the view gets re-rendered and so the current values of the username and password which I still need to be displayed on the page, gets overridden by the defaults set in the model. How can I maintain the values of the username and password fields even when the view is re-rendered? I feel like I am missing something fundamental. I am new to Backbone.js. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are not taking the user to the "home" page after validating `username` and `password` in the backend...why would you want to hold those values when the user refreshes the page?

Comment: Actually I am taking them to the home page. I didn't mention that here. Yeah once the user logs in, he is redirected to the home page. I don't want the user to get logged out when he refreshes the page, so to speak.

Comment: Still waiting for someone to enlighten me.